# How can I create a component in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I thought I was on the right track, but I'm getting this error

```
Attempted import error: 'Navigation' is not exported from '../components/navigation'.
```

My component Navigation:

```js
const Navigation = () => (
    <div>
        <span>Home</span>
        <span>About</span>
    </div>
);
    
export default Navigation;
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably trying to import this way:

```js
import { Navigation } from '../components/Navigation';
```

While you should do:

```js
import Navigation from '../components/Navigation';
// or
import Whatever from '../components/Navigation';

// ...
// ...

<Navigation />
// or
<Whatever />
```

For a not default export, you then would do:

```js
import { Navigation } from '../components/Navigation';
```

for a component exported with

```js
const Navigation = () => {};
export Navigation;
```